# The best way to get from Stockholm to Kolmården zoo by public transport

Tags: public-transport, sweden, stockholm, zoos

I'm going to visit Stockholm with kids and wonder what is the best option to get to the Kolmården zoo. My first thought was to take the train as the fastest transport, but as far as I understand, trains station is not that close to the Zoo.

So, what will be better: to get to the train station and go by local bus or to take the bus from the very beginning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this kind of question, [resrobot](http://reseplanerare.resrobot.se/) is an excellent tool.

It appears the quickest transport is a combination of train and bus:

- Train Stockholm – Norrköping; for example, 07:59 - 09:23, 08:21 - 09:33, or 09:40 - 11:11.
- Bus 432 or 433 Norrköping – Kolmården.  For example, 10:00 - 10:09, or 11:47 - 12:00.

Kolmården Djurpark is 27 km from the Norrköping central station.  Waiting times between train and bus appear rather long (more than 30 minutes).  If you're many, you could consider taking a taxi.  When booked via SJ, a taxi costs roughly 600 SEK, but a look at the prices for [Taxikurir Norrköping](http://www.taxikurir.se/orterisverige/norrkoping/taxikurirnorrkoping/varapriser.4.7017056e11fcce66e6580001018.html) suggests it's probably less than 400 SEK there (I get 330 SEK based on their prices).  This can be compared to the bus, which costs 74 SEK for an adult and 51 SEK for youth or senior; so for a family of 2 parents, 2 children, the bus would be 250 SEK.

Answer (score 4):

The train/bus combo is certainly the quickest with public transportation.

A cheap alternative may be [swebus](http://www.swebus.se). It is a 3 to 4 hour ride with one stop-over in Norrköping. The ticket price seems to depend a lot - a roundtrip for a random day this summer is about 400 SEK for one person and about 1000 SEK for 2+2 persons.

Travelling with kids sure is something extra!

UPDATE: removed the Strömma bus option since it is not in service anymore. Thanks to Nitish for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to take the regional train from Stockholm to Kolmaarden, a station located in Krokek. From there buses 432 and 433 connect to the zoo.

You can go via Norrköping, but it's a detour, as all buses from there will pass through Kolmaarden station en route anyway, and that station is **before** Norrköping coming from Stockholm.